# Getting HTTP 500 error at end of update process when going from Craft 2 to Craft 3 with MAMP

Tags: craft3, error, updates

When I try to perform an update from Craft 2 to Craft 3 I am getting a 500 error at, what appears to be, the end of the process. No other info is given.

I am using MAMP Pro V4 for Mac.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try switching MAMP out of Fast CGI mode. Go to the PHP Tab and select "Identical PHP Version for all hosts (Module mode)". Restart the servers and then. Then run the update.

You can normally switch back to Fast CGI mode at this point and it will continue to work OK. But if you do run into this, or a file upload problem, it's worth changing to Module mode temporarily as it often fixes whatever is causing the issue.

Comment: It worked but why!?

Comment: ¯|_(ツ)_|¯ no idea.